# Idiomatic C++ syntax for "maybe-move" parameter passing

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

Consider a `map`-like type with slightly different behavior on the `emplace` operation: While it accepts `Key&&` and `Val&&` arguments, it *guarantees* me that any argument I pass it will remain unchanged if the key is not inserted.

I want to implement an `insert_or_update` type function (I realize this is *not* the way you would actually do it, but stick with me for an example).

```
my_map_type::iterator iter;
bool                  inserted_new;
std::tie(iter, inserted_new) = my_map.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
if (!inserted_new)
    iter->second = std::move(val);
```

Someone looking at this code will think there is a bug: I am using `val` after I have already said `std::move(val)`.

---

The most reasonable thoughts I have are to change `emplace` to return an `optional<Val>` instead of just a `bool`. If the key is not inserted, it will be returned to you.

```
my_map_type::iterator iter;
std::optional<Val>    returned_val;
std::tie(iter, returned_val) = my_map.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(val));
if (returned_val)
    iter->second = std::move(*returned_val);
```

The problem with this solution is performance. The most obvious issue is that it only works reasonably if moving your `Val` is absurdly cheap. Another problem is that under -O3, my original example does not touch the stack, while the latter puts `returned_val` on it (when `Val = std::uint64_t` on a 64-bit Linux machine with GCC 5.2).

---

**Question**: Is there a way to maintain the safety of my latter option while still getting the performance benefits of the former?

Comment: This is basically [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) and [`insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign); both use your first interface.